# Haskell call function onload

Tags: function, haskell, call, onload

Good morning fellow programmers!

i'm working on a project using haskell, and i've wanted to know how to run a haskell function without having to type two lines on ghci, for example

```
ghci filename.hs function
```

This can only be done doing:

```
 ghci filename.hs
function
```

????
I'm looking for something like the main () in C,which runs automatically when you compile the program
Is there something like that? 
I've been checking the -e option on ghci, but i cant seem to get it to work!

Thank you very much!

Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

You're probably looking for `ghc -e` instead:

```
> echo 'foo x y z = x+y*z' > foo.hs  % let's make a foo.hs file
> ghc foo.hs -e 'foo 1 2 3'          % call the function in foo.hs
=> 7
```

Also, note that you can also use the `:reload` command in ghci. Load the file in ghci, edit, type `:reload` and test again. Also, if this seems too tedious, you can also define a ghci macro which allows you to reload and test your function at the same time:

```
> :def test \x -> return (":reload\n" ++ x)
> :test foo 1 2 3
=> Ok, modules loaded: Foo.
7
```

If you're looking to build real programs instead of quickly testing
your functions, then you'd better read the other answers on writing 
`main` functions.

Comment: +1 Examples of using `ghc -e` from the command line *and* `:def` in ghci? Nice!

Answer (score 6):

I assume `function` has the type `IO ()`. Then you can just let `main = function`, and use for example `runhaskell modulename` from the command line. As in C, `main` is a special function.

To clarify a bit, just in case: If your `function` is a pure one, i.e. one whose type does not invovle `IO`, you can't really "run it". I guess it's a simplification to say this, but essentially what GHCi does is to call `print function`. If you want to mimic this, you can use something like `main = print function` and use `runhaskell`. This assumes `function`'s type is an instance of `Show`.

Comment: The recently-released [ReadArgs](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/nsxwz/readargs10_now_on_hackage/) library could make the `main` + `runhaskell` option quite nice, if you want to pass args to the function at the command line.